# HTML5 and swiffy files in DFP

Tags: html, google-dfp, google-swiffy

I trying to work out what to do after I've converted my SWF to HTML5 via Swiffy. Once converted I get a something.html file, which although great doesn't help with getting into DFP.  Any tools that will give me the HTML5 code? Or unpackage the SWF so I can upload the frames?

Many thanks,

Comment: The HTML (5) code is something.html, but that isbt accepted in dfp. Swf (flash) is. Why are you converting it? What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

I accomplished that by copy and pasting the content of the something.html to a new Third Party creative in DFP.

The HTML content goes inside de "Code Snippet" box

Reply me if you still have problems...

Comment: How did you deal with the clickThrough etc? A code example would be great.

Comment: @kevinMario, I don't know about clickThrough, but **clickTag** is explained here: https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/6263155?hl=en

Comment: sure, but when you paste the code into the Third Party Creative that means you'll have to hard code the destination URL into the code? How do you deal with tracking if the destination URL is inside the code itself? ( yes, I was talking about clickTag - my bad! )

Comment: About the hard code: yes. Didn't find a solution for that. Found a place to inset MACROS but there is NO place to set it.
I think DCM ou Studio have an answer for it. But Google didn't give me a account, so I don't know how they work.

About tracking clicks, no idea either. The solution is the CLICK MACRO, but again, no place to set it, just to insert it.

Comment: CMIIW, but if you insert Click Macro BEFORE the hard-coded URL, your creative should now be able to track # of clicks.